# "No route matches [POST]" when changing link_to to button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, hyperlink

I have this piece of code:

```
<%= link_to "New User", new_user_path, :class => "button"  %><br />
```

which works fine, but when I change it to,

```
<%= button_to "New User", new_user_path, :class => "button"  %><br />
```

I get this error

> No route matches [POST] "/users/new"

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Jesus Rodriguez is right about POST and GET, but if you really need the button you can simply override the default method:

```
<%= button_to "New User", new_user_path, :class => "button", :method => :get  %>
```

Answer (score 19):

The "link_to" is looking for a */users/new* using **GET**.

The "button_to" is looking for a */users/new* using **POST**

If you create the routes for a controller using:

```
resources :user
```

By default, */users/new* is a **GET** and not **POST** so, the second line doesn't find any route.

If you are thinking to change that action to **POST** I think that you should forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

button_to defaults to POST, and link_to defaults to GET, this is why links_to worked. You can force button_to to use GET:

```
<%= button_to "New User", new_user_path, :class => "button", :method => :get %>
```

You can get more information about button_to options here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forcing button_to to use a non-default method, you can also send a class to link_to.

```
<%= link_to "New User", new_user_path, :class => "button" %>
```

Comment: To add to that, you can add classes to that to make it "look" like a button (as the answer shows above). In my case I am using bootstrap and did the following

`<%= link_to "New User", new_user_path, :class => "btn btn-default" %>`