# Routing Error - No route matches [POST] "/xvaziris/125/hide"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I wanted to hide the records on button click temporarily with carrying forward the running balance.

Please refer the screen-shot for better understanding as shown below;

[image: image.png]

When I clicked the "Hide" button, I keep running into the following error:

No route matches [POST] "/xvaziris/125/hide"

Please refer the screen-shot for better understanding as shown below;

[image: screenshot.png]

As I mentioned the method: :get in my partial but still it gives me the post routing error.

I tried running rake routes and I can see that the route exists:

```
C:\Users\pos1\Desktop\offorgs>bundle exec rake routes
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
               root GET    /                              xvaziris#index
       **hide_xvaziri GET    /xvaziris/:id/hide(.:format)   xvaziris#hide**
           xvaziris GET    /xvaziris(.:format)            xvaziris#index
                    POST   /xvaziris(.:format)            xvaziris#create
        new_xvaziri GET    /xvaziris/new(.:format)        xvaziris#new
       edit_xvaziri GET    /xvaziris/:id/edit(.:format)   xvaziris#edit
            xvaziri GET    /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#show
                    PATCH  /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#update
                    PUT    /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#update
                    DELETE /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#destroy
    import_xvaziris POST   /xvaziris/import(.:format)     xvaziris#import
                    GET    /xvaziris(.:format)            xvaziris#index
                    POST   /xvaziris(.:format)            xvaziris#create
                    GET    /xvaziris/new(.:format)        xvaziris#new
                    GET    /xvaziris/:id/edit(.:format)   xvaziris#edit
                    GET    /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#show
                    PATCH  /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#update
                    PUT    /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#update
                    DELETE /xvaziris/:id(.:format)        xvaziris#destroy
xvaziri_resetfilter GET    /xvaziri/resetfilter(.:format) xvaziris#reset_filter
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


    root 'xvaziris#index'

    resources :xvaziris do
        member do
            get :hide
        end
    end

    resources :xvaziris do 
        collection { post :import }
    end


    get '/xvaziri/resetfilter', to: 'xvaziris#reset_filter'

end
```

xvaziris_controller.rb

```
class XvazirisController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_xvaziri, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.find_by hidden: false
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html 
        end 
    end

    def import
        Xvaziri.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to xvaziris_url, notice: "Xvaziris imported."
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new
    end

    def create
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new(xvaziri)
        if
            @xvaziri.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Created'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @xvaziri.update(xvaziri)
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Updated'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @xvaziri.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully destroyed.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    def hide
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
        @xvaziri.hidden = true
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    def reset_filter
        xvaziris = Xvaziri.all
        xvaziris.each do |xvaziri|
            xvaziri.hidden = false
        end
        redirect_to xvaziris_url
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_xvaziri
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def xvaziri
        params.require(:xvaziri).permit(:date, :description, :amount, :discount, :paid)
    end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="table-responsive myTable">

                <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="tr-head">
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                        <td>Button</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>              
                        <%= render @xvaziris %>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<br>
<br> 
<br> 

<%= link_to "Show all", xvaziri_resetfilter_path %>
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<tr   class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color xvaziri.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% @balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1"><%= button_to "Hide", controller: "xvaziris", action: "hide", id: xvaziri, method: :get %></td>

</tr>
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked this up and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475397/3901075) thread about the opposite issue. According to one of the answers:

> The "link_to" is looking for a /users/new using GET.
>
> The "button_to" is looking for a /users/new using POST
>
> If you create the routes for a controller using:
>
> resources :user By default, /users/new is a GET and not POST so, the
>   second line doesn't find any route.

Maybe you can try changing it to link_to?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= button_to "Hide", hide_xvaziri_path(xvaziri), method: :get %>
```

u can also try using link_to and apply some css to it.

```
 <%= link_to "Hide", hide_xvaziri_path(xvaziri)%>
```

By default button_to is for post method and link_to is for get method

Answer (score 1):

It shows a GET request route for hide, not a POST request. `hide_xvaziri GET    /xvaziris/:id/hide(.:format)   xvaziris#hide`. Try to add a POST request manually and check.

```
post '/xvaziri/:id/hide', to: 'xvaziris#hide'
```